# apply div width to unchilded ul

Tags: html, css

How do I apply the width of the div to the ul, when the width of the div is unknown.

The HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>
        Text
    </p>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>
            Some other text
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the ul should be 89% smaller in width than the div.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<ul>` is outside the `<div>` then it has no concept of the `<div>`s width. You could do it with javascript if you wanted to.

jQuery approach (who knows if this is what you actually want, but your question is... vague)

```
$('ul').css('width', $('div').width() * 0.89);
```

Comment: I guess that you can change the $('ul) with a class instead, like $('.classname')

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
var ulWidth = parseInt($("div").width() * .89);
$("ul").width(ulWidth);
```

I split the JS into 2 lines for readability, but you can do this with just one line:

```
$("ul").width(parseInt($("div").width() * .89));
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/9dzTM/3/)** with alert for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

With **jQuery** :

```
var width = $('div').width() * 0.89;

$('ul').css({'width':width});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/swXQH/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul").width(parseInt($("div").width()) * 0.89);
```